# Automatic transfer of users' phone numbers from 'Active Directory on-premises' to MFA field in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

In my organization we're running a kind of hybrid environment - we use both Active Directory on-premises and Azure AD.
We'd like to use MFA functionality in AAD and enter employee phone numbers in 'Authentication method'
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S42NT.png)
Employees phone numbers are already present on users' cards in AD on-premises (General or Telephones tab).
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVe3S.png)

---

Therefore, I have the following questions:

1. Does anyone know a way to automatically transfer data from AD on-premises to the appropriate MFA field in AAD? Via Power Automate, Powershell, whatever - the technology doesn't matter, the point is not to manually flip the data :)
2. If there is no chance to transfer such data from AD on-premises, maybe there is an option to treat creating a new user's account as a trigger to the action of copying his/her number from this field:
   [Phone number on general tab - for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuyuJ.png)
   to MFA [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4BOh.png)

---

I'd be incredibly grateful - for any advice :)

If you have any ideas other than **Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Signins**

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userdevicesettings](https://stackoverflow.com)

which unfortunately didn't work in this case, that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Automatic transfer of users' phone numbers from 'Active Directory on-premises' to MFA field in Azure Active Directory

As per [MS DOC](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sync-authentication-contact-information-from-on/4acca20a-0161-43c5-a1af-c9f75ad0e9b2) it is not possible do directly sync the Authentication contact information from **On-Prem AD** to **Azure AD**, as these attributes are cloud only attributes, Follow the [Authentication contact info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-authenticationdata)

In order to update the **On-prem** users phone number to **Azure AD Authentication method**.you can follow below steps.

1. Export **On-prem AD** user details to **CSV** file using below powershell code.

   ```
   Import-Module ActiveDirectory
   Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, EmailAddress, Description | Export-Csv -Path   C:\Users.csv -NoTypeInformation
   ```

**Output:**

[image]

Once export the user details, you can use below powershell  code to update **Authentication contact information** to **Azure AD**.

```
    Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Force
    connect-graph -Scopes @("UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All";"UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All")
   $inputfile = "/home/mt/EnableMFA.csv"
    $data=Import-Csv -Path $inputfile
    foreach ($user in $data) 
    { 
        $upn = $user.upn 
        $phone = $user.phonenumber 
        try 
        { 
            New-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod -UserId $upn -PhoneNumber $phone -PhoneType "mobile" 
            Write-Host "Phone number $phone updated successfully for user $upn." 
        } 
        catch 
        { 
            Write-Host "Error updating phone number $phone for user $upn" 
        } 
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once ran the above code **Phone numbers** are updated in **Azure AD**.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Thank you very much for your help and kindness :) Works perfect. 
For those who are still interested in this topic I suggest to also get familiar with this info (to update policy/phone numbers; not only creating new ones): 
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/beta/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-update.md